# Naming current Redis master (run in Docker) in Python

Tags: python, docker-compose, redis-cluster, redis-sentinel

How to make Python failover to Redis slave if master is down?

With current configuration, Sentinels elect a new master, but Python writes stop.

I assume I should not use redis-master as is in docker-compose.yml file; what are the alternatives?

In networking mode, I couldn't get Sentinels to recognize each other.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:

  redis-master:
    container_name: redis-master
    image: redis:latest
    command: redis-server --port 6379
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    volumes:
      - .:/app

  redis-slave:
    container_name: redis-slave
    image: redis:latest
    command: redis-server --slaveof redis-master 6379 --protected-mode no
    volumes:
       - .:/app

  sentinel-1:
    container_name: sentinel-1
    build: sentinel
    environment:
      - SENTINEL_DOWN_AFTER=5000
      - SENTINEL_FAILOVER=5000

  sentinel-2:
    container_name: sentinel-2
    build: sentinel
    environment:
      - SENTINEL_DOWN_AFTER=5000
      - SENTINEL_FAILOVER=5000

  sentinel-3:
    container_name: sentinel-3
    build: sentinel
    environment:
      - SENTINEL_DOWN_AFTER=5000
      - SENTINEL_FAILOVER=5000

  app:
    container_name: python-app
    image: pyredis
    command: python app.py
```

Python app:

```
import redis
import random
import time

r = redis.StrictRedis(host="redis-master", port=6379, db=0)

for i in range(0, 1000):
    timestamp = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.gmtime())
    num = random.randint(1,101)
    r.set(timestamp, num)
    time.sleep(2)
```

Thank you, any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need a function to re-define what your `r` value is:

```py
import redis
from redis.exceptions import ConnectionError

def get_connection(host):
    global r
    other_host = "redis-slave" if "master" in host else "redis-master"

    try:
        r = redis.StrictRedis(host=host, port=6379, db=0)
    except ConnectionError:
        # connection against host failed, try other_host
        host = other_host
        r = redis.StrictRedis(host=host, port=6379, db=0)
    return host


host = get_connection('redis-master')

for i in range(0, 1000):
    timestamp = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.gmtime())
    num = random.randint(1,101)
    try:
        r.set(timestamp, num)
    # handles explicitly redis.exceptions.ConnectionError
    except ConnectionError: 
        host = get_connection(host)
        r.set(timestamp, num)
    time.sleep(2)
```

In the case of master going down, that function will be called and the connection will be switched to the slave, and vice versa. If both are down, the `Exception` caught by the outer `except` will be raised and the program will crash

## Edit

This could be a really interesting use-case for mutable defaults which normally is a [BIG NO-NO](https://dev.to/florimondmanca/python-mutable-defaults-are-the-source-of-all-evil-6kk). **Note**, I would still not implement this in any production code, just showing the side-effect here

A deque supports in-place rotation, so you can use that to switch `host` and `other_host` like so:

```py
from collections import deque

d = deque(('redis-master', 'redis-slave'), maxlen=2)

d
deque(['redis-master', 'redis-slave'], maxlen=2)

d.rotate()
d
deque(['redis-slave', 'redis-master'], maxlen=2)
```

Now, you can use that as your cache and just swap the order

```py
def get_connection(d=deque(('redis-master', 'redis-slave'), maxlen=2)):
    global r
    host, other_host = d # unpacks the two values

    try:
        r = redis.StrictRedis(host=host, port=6379, db=0)
    except ConnectionError:
        r = redis.StrictRedis(host=other_host, port=6379, db=0)
        d.rotate() # changes the order of the hosts
```

To show how this works:

```py
def get_connection(d=deque(('redis-master', 'redis-slave'), maxlen=2)):
    print(d)
    try:
        raise ValueError # as a test
    except ValueError:
        print("Caught error")
        d.rotate()
        print(d)


get_connection()
deque(['redis-master', 'redis-slave'], maxlen=2)
Caught error
deque(['redis-slave', 'redis-master'], maxlen=2)

get_connection()
deque(['redis-slave', 'redis-master'], maxlen=2)
Caught error
deque(['redis-master', 'redis-slave'], maxlen=2)
```

Now your external program doesn't need to know about `host`, it would just have to call the retry function as necessary:

```py
for i in range(0, 1000):
    timestamp = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.gmtime())
    num = random.randint(1,101)
    try:
        r.set(timestamp, num)
    # handles explicitly redis.exceptions.ConnectionError
    except ConnectionError: 
        get_connection() # host doesn't need to be returned anymore
        r.set(timestamp, num)
    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you perhaps think Redis will raise an error here? Such as ConnectionError? (https://redis-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/redis/exceptions.html)

Comment: probably a `ConnectionError` in this particular case